# Display printer dialog

Tags: java

I use the following line of code to have Adobe Reader print my generated PDF:

```
desktop.print(new File("temp.pdf"));
```

It always uses the standard printer.

Is there a way to display the "choose printer" dialog instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html

Comment: The java tutorial is (as usual) very informative, but it doesn´t tell me how i can use the Desktop.print() method to print via another application (in this case AcroReader) AND use a PrinterJob to display a dialog. Or i keep missing something, which wouldn´t surprise me either :)